# Question about the solution of linear system of equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

Given,$A$ be a $n\times n $ real matrix.
$(1)$ $Ax=b$ , where $b\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times 1 }$
$(2)$ $A'Ax=A'b $ , where $A'$ is transpose of $A$

**(a)** both $(1),(2)$ may not have solution.
**(b)** $(1)$ may not have solution, but $(2)$ always have solution.

For $(1)$ it's clear that whenever $b$ is not in the column space of $A$ ,then $Ax=b$ have no solution.

For $(2)$ , is it always possible that $A'b$ is in the column space of $A'A$?

Please help me here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\mathcal{C}(A'A)\subseteq\mathcal{C}(A')$$
Now $Ax=0\implies A'Ax=0$, so null space of $A$ is a subset of nullspace of $A'A$. Also $$A'Ax=0\implies x'A'Ax=0\implies\|Ax\|=0\implies Ax=0.$$ Hence we also have the reverse inclusion, that the null space of $A'A$ is contained in the nullspace of $A$. Hence we have $\mathrm{nullity}(A)=\mathrm{nullity}(A'A)$, which implies $$\mathrm{rank}(A'A)=\mathrm{rank}(A)=\mathrm{rank}(A')$$

Thus we must have $\mathcal{C}(A'A)=\mathcal{C}(A')$. For any $b$, $A'b\in \mathcal{C}(A')=\mathcal{C}(A'A)$.

Comment: So, then why is option (a) given true? Is the given answer wrong then?

Comment: Also, $A'b$ is the image space of $A'$, is it coincide with column space of $A'$?

Comment: option $(b)$ is true. (2) will always have a solution.

Comment: Whenever two matrices have equal rank, then they have equal column space. Is it always true? Or is it work only for $A'A,A'$? If it is,,can you please give me some proof or theorem about this?

Comment: Suppose $W$ is a subspace of vector space $V$. Then if $\dim(W)=\dim(V)$, then we have $V=W$. 

Use this fact for the column spaces of $A'A$ and $A'$. $\mathcal{C}(A'A)\subseteq\mathcal{C}(A')$ and $\dim(\mathcal{C}(A'A))=\mathrm{rank}(A'A)=\mathrm{rank}(A')=\dim(\mathcal{C}(A'))$

Comment: Thank you!!!!!!